# SQL Server convert datetime to MM/DD/CCYY HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server, how can I convert date format to `MM/DD/CCYY HH:MM:SS`.

`CCYY` not working:

```
select format(getdate(), 'MM/dd/CCYY HH:MM:ss')
```

Comment: what version of SQL Server?. Also, what do you mean is not working?, what does the `CC` part of `CCYY` means?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5582.0 (X64) 
 Feb 27 2015 18:10:15 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: you should use `yyyy` instead of `CCYY`, I don't even know what `CC` is supposed to mean

Comment: `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss')`

Comment: i don't want to use yyyy, i need CCYY

Comment: then can't you at least explain what is `CC` supposed to mean?

Comment: not sure but its century, still i am not sure, so i asked question here.
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2258913?tstart=0

Comment: Also, note that `MM` is months, if you want minutes you need `mm` - so it should probably be `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: SQL Server uses .NET string formatting under the covers, and .NET string formatting for dates does **not** support a `C` character - you'll need to just use `YYYY` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My US based client confirm that CCYY is equal to YYYY.
Oracle supports CCYY. In SQL Server i have to use YYYY.